# Cannot find module 'mongodb-client-encryption'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, browserify

I have a script.js file, there requires `mongodb` module, and when I want to run it with browser, it say that require is not defined.So, I installed `browserify` using `npm`, but when i want to use it `browserify script.js -o all.js -d`, I get an error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb-client-encryption' from
> 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\browserify\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations'

Comment: Install the missing module with `npm install mongodb-client-encryption`

Answer (score 5):

As per comment, you need to install [mongodb-client-encryption](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-client-encryption) module. This is a Node.JS wrapper for [libmongocrypt](https://github.com/mongodb/libmongocrypt/).

```
npm install mongodb-client-encryption
```

If you're seeing an error message related to this module, i.e.:

```
TypeError: encryption.createDataKey is not a function
```

Check the module import line, it should be:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const { ClientEncryption } = require('mongodb-client-encryption');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
```

See also:

- [github.com/mongodb-labs/field-level-encryption-sandbox](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/field-level-encryption-sandbox/blob/master/node/helloWorld.js)
- [MongoDB Node.JS: Client Side Encryption examples](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/reference/client-side-encryption/#examples)

Comment: What is MongoDB that is passed as an argument in require('mongodb-client-encryption')(MongoDB) ?

Comment: @Kapil Updated the code snippet above. It should be the `mongodb` import.

Comment: thanks. It seems the package has been updated and now const { ClientEncryption } = require('mongodb-client-encryption') works and it does not expect passing MongoDB as argument now.